# How to solve Xamarin Android build error XA4215

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

Hi I am new to xamarin and have encountered some errors trying to migrate Xamarin to maui and I'm not sure how to solve. I understand that I am supposed to change the [Register] attribute on one of the C# types to a different Java type name. But how do I do that. Any advice would be appreciated.

Error   XA4215  The Java type `xamarin.essentials.fileProvider` is generated by more than one managed type. Please change the [Register] attribute so that the same Java type is not emitted.

Error   XA4215    `xamarin.essentials.fileProvider` generated by: Xamarin.Essentials.FileProvider, Xamarin.Essentials, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null

Error   XA4215    `xamarin.essentials.fileProvider` generated by: Microsoft.Maui.Essentials.FileProvider, Microsoft.Maui.Essentials, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null

Comment: Maybe this is related? - [the-java-type-is-generated-by-more-than-one-managed-type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66189981/the-java-type-is-generated-by-more-than-one-managed-type)

Answer (score 0):

For me I was referencing https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/StoreReviewPlugin which automatically brings in Xamarin Essentials. I think that package needs to be updated to reference Maui Essentials.

Wonder if you have something similar in a package.